# How to get an image loaded in pygame with it needing to be in the same folder as the .py?

Tags: python, pygame

So with this code I was able to load up a little skeleton I had made.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
img = pygame.image.load("./User_Skeleton_Walk_1.1.bmp")

white = (255, 255, 255)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
screen.fill((white))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((white))
    screen.blit(img,(10,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

However I am just getting started on this project and wanted it to me organized so I made a few folders to help. Now the problem I'm having is that the image I want to load has to be in the same file location as the .py. This makes all my images bundled into one folder that's sloppy and unorganized. Is there a way to load an image without it needing to be in the same file location as the .py?

I've already tried loading it from the C: drive to the image location but that still wasn't able to load it.

I'm using Python 3.5 and the pygame 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
img = pygame.image.load("./FOLDER/User_Skeleton_Walk_1.1.bmp")
```